# Accidentally delete Ubuntu swap and main partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning

When I start my PC it boots me the Grub rescue place
It says error no partition found
How do I fix this thing
I tried set prefix and set root those things but still it says error.
Please help me.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the swap partition, that's no big deal, but deleting the Ubuntu ´/´ partition, is basically deleting all of Ubuntu except the grub MBR.  So you have the following options:

1. The only *sure* thing you can do is a full reinstall and then a restore of your most recent back-up
2. If you split the HDD into a `` and `/home ``when you first installed the system, just a reinstall will be sufficient
3. If you don't have a backup, you *might* be able to restore some files using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

That's basically it!